# Inheritance - Get base type grandparents

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

In my ViewStart file I need to render a different layout based on the controller type that is rendering the view.

I need to determine whether a controller, on the lowest level, derives from the VehicleController.

So let's say I have an inheritance model like this:

```
CarController: VehicleController

FordController: CarController

FordFocusController: FordController
```

Now, within the FordFocusController, I have a simple Index() method returning a View.

So in the ViewStart, I can determine the controller like so:

```
ViewContext.Controller.GetType().BaseType // returns FordController - correct!
```

Now, for the FordFocusController, this will return FordController.

However, how can I tell if this is a type of VehicleController, which in this case, it is on its lowest level?

E.g. I don't want to have to do something like this as it's not dynamic!

```
ViewContext.Controller.GetType().BaseType.GetType().BaseType.GetType()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In C#, there is the keyword '[is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)' for that.

You can use it as

```
if (ViewContext.Controller is VehicleController)
{
 ...
}
```

In your inheritance structure

```
CarController: VehicleController  

FordController: CarController

FordFocusController: FordController
```

There could be those examples:

```
var cc = new VehicleController();
var fc = new FordController();
var ffc = new FordFocusController();

var direct = (fc is VehicleController); // true, a ford controller is also a vehicle controller
var indirect = (ffc is VehicleController); // true, a ford focus controller is also a vehicle controller

//cast it to a variable
if (ffc is VehicleController myVehicleController) 
{
    ....here you can use myVehicleController of type VehicleController
}
```

greetings,

Mike

Comment: You can allocate the casted version to a variable by doing `is VehicleController myVariable`